# Jenkins email-ext, pre-send script: How to replace Jira Issue string directly with a link to the issue?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

a question about the pre-send script possibility of email-ext:
At the moment, this is the "Default Content" of the Email Notification:

```
<h3>$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS</h3>
<p>
Check console output at $BUILD_URL/console to view the results.
</p>
...
<hr/>
<b>Changes since last build</b><br/>
<div style="padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;">
    ${CHANGES,format="<div><b>%a</b></div><div style=\"padding-left:30px;\"> &#8212; &#8220;<em>%m</em>&#8221;</div><br/>"}
</div>
```

This will include the commit messages in the result email... and as we are giving the Jira issue id with every commit, it would be nice to replace the Jira issue id, e.g. TESTPROJECT-1234 with a link to it.

Can somebody help me, to achieve this behavior?
The best way to do this is to use a regex, right? like

```
    (TESTPROJECT-[1-9][0-9]*)
```

and replace it with

```
    <a href="http://jira.server.com/browse/$1">$1</a>
```

But at the moment I have no glue, how to use groovy and the pre-send script to do this. :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need regular expression. See this script example: https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template that shows you how to loop over your changeset.

Comment: Ok, so one solution is, to use templates... But at the moment I have to use the current one and I'm only trying to achieve the functionality using the pre-send script, which should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

if it is still relevant, below is the script for release note with links as you was looking for

```
import hudson.model.*;
import hudson.util.*;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


println build.getEnvVars()['JiraReleaseNotes']

def txt = build.getEnvVars()['JiraReleaseNotes']

def JiraReleaseNotes2 = txt.replaceAll(/# ([^]]*)/){ all, it ->
    "</br>$all"
}


def JiraReleaseNotes1 = JiraReleaseNotes2.replaceAll(/- \[([^]]*)]/){ all, it ->
    "</br><li><a href=\"http://server.com/browse/${it}\">${it}</a>"
}


println JiraReleaseNotes1

def thr = Thread.currentThread();
def currentBuild = thr.executable;

def newParamAction = new hudson.model.ParametersAction(new hudson.model.StringParameterValue("JiraReleaseNotes2", JiraReleaseNotes1 ));
currentBuild.addAction(newParamAction);
```